# Check array value exist in another array value that contain comma separated value

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays in PHP which are:

```
print_r($vid);  // contain array data
print_r($vidDB); // contain array data
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7
)
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 6,7
)
```

Now, I need to check if the 7 **(from variable `$vid`)** exists in a variable `$vidDB`.

How can I do this using PHP?

I have tried with

```
array_intersect($vid, $vidDB)
```

but no luck :(

Comment: Do you just need to know it exists, or which element it's in?

Comment: well the array $vidDB has comma seperated values so its considered a single string value.

Comment: Will the `$vid` only have 1 element? What is your expected output exactly?

Comment: @NigelRen basically I need show a message if the 7 exists in variable `$vidDB`. True and false should be enough.

Comment: @Eddie both variable are an Array.

Comment: @ShibbirAhmed but is it possible for `$vid` to have multiple values?

Comment: @Eddie Yes, it can contain multiple value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use preg_grep.
I use implode($vid) in case you have multiple search values.
Edit replaced `[]` in regex with `\b` to fix what Nigel pointed out.

```
$vid = [7];
$vidDB = [5,4,"6,71"];

$return = preg_grep("/\b" . implode("\b|\b", $vid) . "\b/", $vidDB);
Var_dump($return);
```

https://3v4l.org/pXPBv

If $return has any values it's true.
So you could use `if(count($return) >0)` as your true/false statement

Edit: with multiple search values and true/false output: https://3v4l.org/3VB3a

```
if(count($return) >0){
    Echo "true";
}Else{
    Echo "false";
}
```

Comment: Can I get true or false value if the value exists in another array?

Comment: I just edited the question, I saw your comment above

Comment: Just wanted to point out that this fails if you just replace the last element with `6,71`, still says true.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `implode` and `explode` combo to list all the array on `$vidDB`. You can use `array_intersect` to find the common array elements

```
$vid    = array('7');
$vidDB  = array('5','4','6,7');

$vidDB2 = explode(',',implode(',',$vidDB)); //Flatten the array using implode and explode
$common = array_intersect($vid, $vidDB2);   //Check the common array

$count = count($common);                    //To return the number

echo "<pre>";;
print_r( $common );
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: can I get true or false value? because I need to show an error message.

Comment: Just add `count($common)>0`, was just writing very similar answer - even down to using `$vidDB2` :(

Comment: Just Great.. :)

Comment: Why do you array_intersect twice?

Comment: @Andreas I just copy and paste. Good catch. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the 7 is a string in the array then I don’t imagine you can use a simple php function. You’d be best creating a function which loops through the vidDB array and uses `explode(‘,’, $vidDB[i])` to check if the seven exists in the string.

I’m not sure how you’re selecting 7 to be the number to search for in the second array though.

Comment: 7 is not a string. It's an array data

Comment: @ShibbirAhmed it’s not an array because it doesn’t contain the surrounding brackets if you look at the output

Comment: Please look it carefully. It's has []

Comment: @ShibbirAhmed I’m talking about in the second array where it is a string like [“6,7”]

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly what you're looking for

```
<?php

function ifNumberExists($vid, $vidDB) {
    $status = false;
    $vidDBItemArray = array();
    foreach($vid as $vidItem) {
        foreach($vidDB as $vidDBItem) {
            $vidDBItemArray = str_split($vidDBItem);
            foreach($vidDBItemArray as $vidDBItemArrayValue) {
                if($vidItem == $vidDBItemArrayValue) {
                    $status = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $status;
}

?>
```